# Port forward localhost:port to lan:port using iptables - how?

Tags: router, iptables, port-forwarding, tomato

Is there a way I can map `127.0.0.1:3389` to `192.168.1.2:3389` (with iptables? That is, all connections to `localhost:3389` will be redirected to my LAN machine?

The reason for that is as follows: my iPhone RDP app can do SSH tunneling but does not provide  options to tweak SSH parameters. So, it connects to my router via SSH, establishes a tunnel to 127.0.0.1:3389 and then tries to connect to `localhost:3389` on the iPhone. Fail.

I don't want to run SSH server on my LAN machine and instead want to use router's SSH server(Asus RT-N16 running Tomato). Is that doable? This doesn't work:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/)** it seems to do what you want. There is some more information on installation and usage **[here](http://www.lenzg.net/rinetd/rinetd.pdf)**.

Comment: Thanks, rinetd looks promising for the fabled redirect from localhost to alternative host address.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your iptables command:

1) you are trying to catch that in the OUTPUT table, but for a redirection like this you need to do it in PREROUTING

2) you are not redirecting to the port too. you are just telling iptables to send those packets to a certain IP without specifing the port.

So your command should look like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:3389
```

My iptables-fu might be a bit rusty so you if it doesn't work try running the same command in the INPUT table too (-A INPUT). If nothing works, shout back here and we will find a fix.